# Marshalling an array of reference type objects from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke, marshalling

I was able to pass a reference type object successfully from C# to C++ by decorating it with `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)`

The class in C#:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)
public class Point
{
        [DataMember]
        public double X { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

The equivalent in C++:

```
struct Point
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

The function body in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Translate(Point* pt, double dx, double dy)
{
    pt->x += dx;
    pt->y += dy;
}
```

and the equivalent in C#:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static void Translate(Point pt, double dx, double dy);
```

I had no problems till now, the problem happens when I pass an array of these points between the next 2 functions:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double GetArea(Point** vertices,int count, bool isClosed)
    {
        double area = 0;
        if (!isClosed || count < 3) return 0;
        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // j = i+1 except when i = count then j = 0
            j = (i + 1) % count;

            area += vertices[i]->x * vertices[j]->y;
            area -= vertices[i]->y * vertices[j]->x;
        }
        area /= 2;
        return fabs(area);
    }
```

and the C# version:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static double GetArea(Point[] vertices, int count, bool isClosed);
```

is there a specific way to marshal this array? but with keeping the Point class as it is?

the calling method is something that looks like this:

```
public static double GetArea()
        {
            Point[] vertices = { new Point(100, 100), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 100) };
            bool isClosed = true;
            return NativeMethods.GetArea(vertices, vertices.Length, isClosed); //this is the imported C++ method
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier to make the C# `Point` be a blittable value type.

Comment: So `GetArea` has an output parameter that is an array of `Point`? Function declarations aren't quite enough. Who owns the memory? How is it structured? Is `vertices` an array of pointers, or a pointer to an array of values?

Comment: GetArea only returns a double value, it doesn't alter the array of Point.
all the objects are owned by the C# code. and the vertices is just an array of Point in C# public Point[] Vertices { get; private set; }

Comment: So why do you pass a pointer to a pointer to `Point` then? Why isn't it just `Point*`? Are you coding the C/C++ side as well?

Comment: because C# reference types are always passed by reference to C++. I'm coding both sides yes. let me update the question with function bodies

Comment: Does it really make sense to make `Point` a reference type? It makes everything rather complicated (and slow, though how much that matters is of course up to profiling). If you keep it like this, you'd need to manually marshal every single `Point`, put them in memory to resemble an array and pass that.

Comment: @Luaan you are right, it doesn't make sense to use a Point as a reference type, I changed it already to be struct. but out of curiosity and considering Point is still a reference type I'm still confused why am I able to pass a single instance of Point as a reference type and not a whole array?.

Comment: @Dan I'm trying to avoid writing more code as much as possible. I just need to export a couple of functions to be called from C++ by the original C# code.

Comment: @KhaledAlyamany C# does support passing a C-like C# class because that's the only way to have a managed persistent reference to a struct. However, it *always* creates a copy, since apart from a few built-in classes (like arrays and string in some cases), C# classes aren't blittable. It doesn't support passing an array of non-blittable objects - that leaves way too many problems to solve that the marshaller can't really decide. And all that work for a rather rare scenario with easy workarounds :) An array of a blittable type is one allocation of contiguous memory, one pointer, one deallocation.

Comment: @Luaan I got your point, thanks for the explanation :)
so you mean that an array of non-blittable objects in the managed memory  is not allocated contiguously in memory so that's why it cannot be easily marshaled to C/C++?

Comment: Not exactly. You can have non-blittable types that would be allocated contiguously - e.g. `bool[]`. It's just that you're specifically asking for them to be non-contiguous by making `Point` a reference type on the C# side - reference types cannot be "inlined" in arrays. And on the C++ side, you're expecting a pointer to an array of pointers, which also suggests the items *might* be non-contiguous (otherwise you'd just pass an array of values). The core problem is both the non-blittability (which means you can't pass a pointer to the .NET array directly) and the extra pointer indirection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't really be interopping classes at all (with the exception of those explicitly supported, e.g. `string`, arrays...). .NET's native interop is designed for C-style functions and structs, not C++. So either change the native code to be C-style, or use something like C++/CLI to provide a managed interface to the C++ objects and functions.

The simplest way of handling the interop is to use the marshaller, and change `Point` to be a value type, instead of a reference type:

```
struct Point
{
  public double x;
  public double y;
}

[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern unsafe static double GetArea(Point[] vertices, int count, bool isClosed);
```

This of course requires `Point` to be a blittable type - just making it a `struct` instead of `class` should be enough. When `vertices` is a pointer to an array of values, that's all you have to do. The same way, you need to make it a value on the C++ side, rather than a pointer (and the signature of the function would be `GetArea(Point *vertices, ...)`, instead of using a pointer to a pointer).

You have two main options for marshalling an array manually - unsafe code and `IntPtr`. This may be useful if you need to marshal something a bit more complicated

The unsafe signature is simple enough:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern unsafe static double GetArea(Point** vertices, int count, bool isClosed);
```

The way to create and pass the array is the same as in C - I can't really provide anything specific, since it depends entirely on who owns what memory, and how that memory is structured. You can easily work with existing .NET arrays, you'll just need to pin them:

```
public static unsafe double CallGetArea(Point[] vertices, bool isClosed)
{
  if (vertices.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Vertices empty.", "vertices");

  fixed (Point* pVertices = &vertices[0])
  {
    return GetArea(pVertices, vertices.Length);
  }
}
```

This assumes that you just want to pass an array of `Point` values (the signature would have `Point*`). You can't really pass a pointer to an array like this - `pVertices` is read-only. And again, this only works when `Point` is blittable.

The `IntPtr` signature throws away the type information:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern unsafe static double GetArea(IntPtr vertices, int count, bool isClosed);
```

Again, the call is similar to C, you'll just also have to do a lot of annoying marshaller calls both for reading and writing instead of having a C-like language to do that.

If you really want to stick with your idea of making a pointer to an array of pointers to `Point`, things get a bit more complicated. Arrays of pointers aren't supported by the marshaller, so you have to do the marshalling manually. Of course, this involves a lot of copying and allocations that wouldn't be necessary - so if you're trying to do this for performance reasons, don't. The basic idea goes like this:

```
unsafe double CallGetAreaPointers(Point[] vertices, bool isClosed)
{
  var ipArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(vertices.Length * sizeof(Point));
  var ipItems = new Stack<IntPtr>();

  try
  {
    Point** pArray = (Point**)ipArray.ToPointer();

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
      var ipItem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Point));
      ipItems.Push(ipItem);

      Marshal.StructureToPtr(vertices[i], ipItem, false);

      pArray[i] = (Point*)ipItem.ToPointer();
    }

    GetArea(pArray, vertices.Length, isClosed);
  }
  finally
  {
    IntPtr ipItem;
    while ((ipItem = ipItems.Pop()) != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipItem);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipArray);
  }
}
```

(*Disclaimer*: this is just a back-of-the-hand code; if you decide to go this way, make sure you do it right, this is just a general idea)

Note that for simplicity, I'm still using `Point` as a `struct` - it just allows you to use pointers on the C++ side. If you want to go full way and make it a reference type in C#, the easiest way would be to create a `PointStruct` type anyway (private if you want to, it doesn't matter) and copy the classes fields over to the struct. Of course, in either case, there's little point in allocating each and every `Point` instance separately - a simple array of values will work exactly the same way, while being a contiguous bit of memory, much simpler and cheaper to use and cleanup.

Comment: In c++ a struct and a class are almost the same. The first paragraph is very confused. The real issue is not struct vs class, rather it is reference vs value. The code samples you give are not useful because the array is an input. That ref is erroneous and everything that follows is wrong. But the essence is good. Using a value is better. Just the details are awry.

Comment: No. C does not have references. C++ has references, but they are something else. In C# struct vs class is value vs reference. Same thing. In C++ a struct and a class differ only in that members are private by default for class, public by default for struct. Similarly private vs public inheritance. Notwithstanding, `ref Point[] vertices` is still wrong. You want to make `Point` be a value type and use `Point[] vertices` on the C# side. Then `Point *vertices` or `Point vertices[]` on the C++ side.

Comment: Well, I made that point in my very first comment. But the rest of your answer is completely wrong. Starting with that ref.

Comment: My very first comment to the question. How can C++ be inappropriate? This is interop with C++! Throughout this all you ignored my point that your code has always been wrong. `ref Point[]` is never valid for interop. You meant `Point[]`. There is no "since clarified" here. The original question clearly had an array of pointers to structure. It's always been that way. Since the asker controls both ends he is able to, and should, change.

Comment: Nonsense. C# does interop with C++. It's doing it right here. I give up. Never mind.

Comment: `ref Point[]` was wrong all along. What was infuriating was your refusal to consider that you had made a mistake. I'm done. It's all somewhat pointless anyway because the asker has gone away.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The fact that the asker has gone away is the sole reason why I didn't change the answer earlier - I was waiting for him to respond to my questions. And again, why is `ref Point[]` "never valid for interop"? What's wrong about passing a pointer to an array? Sure, it wasn't what the OP wanted to do here, you're right - that was my mistake. I just assumed his interop code was wrong on the C# side, which is extremely common on SO - he didn't say he also writes the native side until I prompted him to. The C++ code made it extremely clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's just crazy that I can communicate clearly with thousands of people, you can communicate clearly with even more (as evidenced by your answers and comments) - and yet we can spend a day arguing something utterly baseless. I've seen a few pairs like this on SO before, and it seems we have the same problem for some reason. I certainly didn't intend to be a pain in the ass, so sorry about that. And all it started with is a bit of C++-bias in your comment and C#-bias in mine; even though we both understand both sides. May us have a better experience next time :)

Comment: How is the native code going to return a newly minted `Point[]`? It can't. That's what is wrong with `ref Point[]`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The native code doesn't - the marshaller handles that. All it needs is a bit of information. I've created a working sample just for you :) https://github.com/Luaancz/RefArrayInterop Of course, I'm not saying this is a useful example - a more realistic scenario where this could be useful would be to have something like an array pool in the native code from which you could extract buffers, but that's a bit trickier. In this example, the marshaller cleans up the unmanaged memory properly (that's why I use `CoTaskMemAlloc` instead of just `new Point[...]`).

Comment: sorry guys for not clarifying more, all what I wanted to do till this moment is passing the array by value or by reference from C# to C++, I don't need it to be modified/returned again.

converting the Point to a value type was the obvious solution from the beginning as you both suggested above, I didn't even have to use unsafe code as Luaan suggested. instead I used the exact same syntax written in my original question.

Comment: @KhaledAlyamany Actually, passing the whole array by value is another matter entirely (and only supported for constant-size arrays in C# AFAIK). You're really choosing between "passing a pointer to an array of values" and "passing a pointer to an array of pointers". And the only way to avoid copying all the items in the array is to use an array of blittable types - all the other approaches are just more or less convoluted ways of doing that copy with respect to what's the interface on the native side.